# SPSS Statistics'table

Tags: spss

How do I create a table in SPSS Statistics where the median and the 25th and 75th percentiles are expressed in parentheses in the cells? Example: 75 ( 40-170 )

I tried using a custom table but the datum inside the cells were divide as median, 25th percentile and 75th percentile as you see in the image. I would like to have a cell with the values together
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbMOk.png)